# Toshiba Satellite C855 is not booting up or going to BIOS and just displaying black screen

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, power-supply, battery, toshiba-laptop

My parents own an old Toshiba Satellite C855 that sits in the office always plugged in. Now it won’t turn on.

When the power button is pressed the LEDs light up and the HDD spins up but the screen stays black. The HDD is pulsing from low to high.

I have tried booting without the PS plugged in, without the battery etc. I’m unable to reach the BIOS with <kbd>F2</kbd>. Could this possibly just be a weak battery.

I’m hoping that the computer doesn’t crash as my father's accounting files are all on there. If need be I might be able to recover the HDD from a Linux live boot but unsure if that would even work if I’m unable to reach bios or boot menu.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the exact make and model number of this Toshiba Satellite. This might be caused by a dead or dying CMOS battery.

Comment: Worst case, pulling the hdd and putting it in another machine should allow you to recover the contents of the  HDD.

Comment: Hopefully your father has a backup of important accounting files, recovery after a failure, isn’t guaranteed

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yes it is a Toshiba Satellite C855

Comment: most likely a dying cmos battery im guessing. i read somewhere online that it might be some caps that are old and are taking a long time to charge but idk

Answer (score 0):

Have you at least tried plugging in an external display to see if possibly the display is messed up or possibly in the case of my old dell laptop the pins that go to the display popped up from the main board causing my display to not turn on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks i was just about to try that actually walking in to the office carrying my monitor. imagine my surprise

Answer (score 0):

i powered the computer on around 7:30 again this morning. I just came into the office now about 11 and it had booted successfully. my next move was to back up the accounting program. needless to say, i think well be shopping for laptops this afternoon.